Which US government policies potentially prohibit [space] contracts with a company run by a drug user?
According to the WSJ:

The world’s wealthiest person has used LSD, cocaine, ecstasy and psychedelic mushrooms, often at private parties around the world, where attendees sign nondisclosure agreements or give up their phones to enter, according to people who have witnessed his drug use and others with knowledge of it. [...] People close to Musk, who is now 52, said his drug use is ongoing, especially his consumption of ketamine, and that they are concerned it could cause a health crisis. Even if it doesn’t, it could damage his businesses.
Illegal drug use would likely be a violation of federal policies that could jeopardize SpaceX’s billions of dollars in government contracts. Musk is intrinsic to the value of his companies, potentially putting at risk around $1 trillion in assets held by investors, tens of thousands of jobs and big parts of the U.S. space program.
SpaceX is the only U.S. company now approved to transport NASA astronauts to and from the International Space Station. [...]
Musk didn’t respond to requests for comment.

Which 'federal policies' likely prohibit giving out [space or other kinds] of contracts to a company run by someone who uses illegal drugs?
And what standard of evidence--if any--is prescribed for the gov't to break such contracts on such basis? (Clearly more than allegations in the [business] press, because those have happened already.)

I think this is more of a legal question suited to law.se then a political one.

@EikePierstorff: it's worded with "federal policies" which is anybody's guess what it might mean. Executive order? CFR? Implicitly stipulated in [NASA] contracts a "morals clause"?

Belongs more on SE.Law, maybe?

The obvious "policy" is the policy of jailing people convicted of felony drug possession.  It's hard to run a $billion company from jail....

@JamesK: TBH, for the ultra-rich, death from OD seems far more likely than any arrest [while they're alive] https://www.bbc.com/news/articles/c624g49qm5mo
